# In Azure AD B2C, Can we force a password reset after N days?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When using [local accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview), can we force a password change every N days?

If not, can we use the graph api to determine the last time the password was changed?

Comment: to: downvoter - how are you going to down vote and request to close it w/o leaving a comment???  What's the issue you see??

Comment: I agree - I upvoted it to make it 0 haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not going to like my answer but...

At this time, Azure AD B2C does not support forced password reset. I would vote for it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16861051-aadb2c-force-password-reset).

At this time, the graph API also doesn't support when a password was last changed. Vote for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/14829738-graph-api-user-last-password-changed-date).

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD B2C Team updated the user voice request [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/16861060-aadb2c-password-expiration).
So now you can use an extension policy to force the password expiration, you can take a look at the code [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days).

Also, the Azure AD Team released a similar feature, updating the user voice request [here](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/14829738-expose-user-last-password-changed-date).

The property is called:

```
lastPasswordChangeDateTime
```

and indeed seems to be the correct one:

> The time when this Azure AD user last changed their password. The date
>   and time information uses ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time.
>   For example, midnight UTC on Jan 1, 2014 would look like this:
>   '2014-01-01T00:00:00Z'

See the updated official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0) for the Graph API.